# Sprite touch detection

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, cgrect

Have a question here. I created a couple sprites (with tags) in my (id)init function, and then merely trying to detect which sprite was touched? A snippet of the code from my init function is pasted below.

```
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"blue_sheet.plist"];
    //create a sprite batch node
    CCSpriteBatchNode *TrainerSprites = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"blue_sheet.png"];
    [self addChild:TrainerSprites z:1];

    //create a sprite from that node
    CCSprite *Horse = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"horse_blue.png"];
    [TrainerSprites addChild:Horse z:1 tag:1];
    //Horse.position = ccp(winSize.width/5, winSize.height/2);
    [Horse setScaleX: 138.5/Horse.contentSize.width];
    [Horse setScaleY: 80/Horse.contentSize.height];

    //create a sprite from that node
    CCSprite *Cow = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"cow_blue.png"];
    [TrainerSprites addChild:Cow z:1 tag:2];
    //Cow.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    [Cow setScaleX: 126/Cow.contentSize.width];
    [Cow setScaleY: 100/Cow.contentSize.height];

    Horse.position = ccp(4*winSize.width/5, winSize.height/2);
    Cow.position = ccp(winSize.width/5, winSize.height/2);

    CGRect pos1 = CGRectMake(Cow.position.x, Cow.position.y, 200, 100);
    CGRect pos2 = CGRectMake(Horse.position.x, Horse.position.y, 200, 100);

    self.touchEnabled = YES;
```

All looks fine... and the sprites appear where they are supposed to. When I touch anywhere on screen my ccTouchBegan function fires. Not seeing anything happen with the CGRect and I suppose I need to determine which one fired by the assigned tag. Yes indeedy, I know I'm missing code, I just cannot locate good solid documentation anywhere how to do this seemingly basic ios functionality. I assume the "sprite touch detection" code should reside inside the ccTouchBegan function? Any help or guidance sincerely appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

to detect the sprite touch you can use this

declare `CCSprite *Cow` in your .h section

and in .m section use this
in init method

```
//create a sprite from that node
    Cow = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"cow_blue.png"];
    [TrainerSprites addChild:Cow z:1 tag:2];
    //Cow.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    [Cow setScaleX: 126/Cow.contentSize.width];
    [Cow setScaleY: 100/Cow.contentSize.height];
```

in touches began method

```
 -(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {    
        UITouch * touch =[touches anyObject];
        CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:[touch view]];
        location =[[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [Cow boundingBox], location)) {

               /* CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
                [scene addChild:[ClassicScene node]];
                [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];*/
            }

    }
```

Comment: Finally getting back to this... Thanks @Abhijit, indeed I was trying something like you suggested earlier. In regard to the code you posted however a couple issues popped up. (1) UITouch line was flagged that "touch" was being redefined, and (2) Cow bounding box was undeclared. Thanks for your ongoing suggestions...

Comment: So in follow-up, where does Cow bounding box need to be declared so the ccTouchBegan routine knows about it? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to subclass CCSprite and implement the [TargetedTouchDelegate](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/tips%3atouchdelegates).

Something like:

```
@interface AnimalSprite:CCSprite<CCTargetedTouchDelegate>
```

The advantage of this approach is that you wont have to do a lot of "If" checks in the layer where you are adding the sprites. The link provides the method that you must implement in orer to implement the protocol and where and how you could register with the touch dispatcher.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will definitely dig into this in more depth later. For now however I'm interested in "simple" as "better". Meaning keep code as simple as possible without adding additional infrastructure. What I really want to do, is detect the sprite tag (as only one sprite will be marked with correct and specific tag, indicating the correct animal was selected). Thanks...